# JFrame background color flashes but then reverts

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paintcomponent

Lately I've been attempting to replicate Space Invaders in java to help with learning about developing applications with java and the programming language in general. However I've run into a little problem with JFrame: the background color that I declared for the window doesn't stay, it just flashes and then reverts to the default. Here's my code:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;`
import java.io.*;`
import javax.swing.*;`
import java.awt.*;`
import java.awt.image.*;`
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;`
import java.awt.event.*;`

public class Invaders extends JPanel{

    public static int x = 40;
    public static int y = 345;
    public static int h = 20;
    public static int k = 180;
    public static int move = 1;
    static final Invaders m = new Invaders();

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Movement of 2d Shapes");
        frame.setSize(404,390);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(m);
        frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Action actionRight = new AbstractAction(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionRightEvent){
                if(x <= 350){
                    x += 10;
                    m.repaint();
                };
            }
        };

        Action actionLeft = new AbstractAction(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionLeftEvent){
                if(x >= 10){
                    x -= 10;
                    m.repaint();
                };
            }
        };

        KeyStroke right = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT");
        KeyStroke left = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT");

        InputMap inputMap = m.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        inputMap.put(right, "RIGHT");
        inputMap.put(left, "LEFT");
        m.getActionMap().put("RIGHT", actionRight);
        m.getActionMap().put("LEFT", actionLeft);

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        draw(g);
        cpu_move(m);
    }

    public void cpu_move(Invaders m){ 
        if(h == 0){
            move = 0;
        }else if(h == 375){
            move = 1;
        }
        if(move == 0){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(60);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            h += 5;
            m.repaint();
        }else if(move == 1){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(60);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            h -= 5;
            m.repaint();
        };
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){
        try{
            g.drawImage(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(
                 "images/Ship.jpg")), x, y, 35, 23, Color.BLACK, null);
            g.drawImage(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(
                 "images/Alien.jpg")), h, k, 28, 20, Color.BLACK, null);
        }catch(IOException k){
            Component temporaryLostComponent = null;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(temporaryLostComponent, 
                  "one or more image files missing or corrupt");
        }
    }
}
```

What's wrong with the declaration of the background color? there are no errors when compiling, but it still does this. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next :

```
frame.getContentPane().add(m);
m.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```

instead of `frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);` because `Invaders m` fills all frame.

Your backgound will be black with image.

Answer (score 1):

```
frame.getContentPane().add(m);
//frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
frame.getContentPane().setBackground( Color.BLACK );
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Top Level Containters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) to understand the structure of a frame. The content pane is painted on top of the frame.

Comment: The good news is that when I change `frame.setBackground()` to `frame.getContentPane().setBackground`, the color doesn't flash anymore. The bad news is that now the background color doesn't display AT ALL. Is there maybe a problem with the placement?

Comment: @user2946438, Well your code has an `add(m)` statement. What is "m". Is it another panel that covers the entire area of the content pane? If so you won't see the background of the content pane and you need to set the background color of the Invaders class.

Comment: @user2946438, also just noticed that your cpu_move() method has a Thread.sleep() method. You should never do a Thread.sleep in a painting() method or on any code that executes on the Event Dispatch Thread. Instead you should use a Swing `Timer` for animation. Read the Swing tutorial. There area sections on `Concurrency` and on `Timers`. Learn the basics of Swing first.